# How do I Open text file and assign all the values to different vectors in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I try to open a text file and to assign all the values to different vector to be able to operate later with everyone of them individually. In my case it tells me that file is not included in directory. I do have .txt file in the project folder and on my desk. Here is my code:

```
int main(){
    
ifstream infile;
infile.open("D://jobs.txt");
vector<int>vec1;
vector<int>vec2;
vector<int>vec3;
int element1, element2, element3;

if(infile.fail()) //Display error if the file failed to open
{
cout<<"Input file failed to open";
}
else
{
    while(infile>>element1 && infile >> element2 && infile>>element3)
    {
    vec1.push_back(element1);
    vec2.push_back(element2);
    vec3.push_back(element3);
    }
}



    return 0;
};
```

Here is my jobs.txt file :

```
1,18,3
2,5,1
3,14,5
4,1,1
5,17,0
6,2,6
7,6,2
8,15,7
9,20,0
10,6,8
```

Comment: Try using a single forward slash in your path. Or use double backslashes.

Comment: still don't understand, just started to learn coding

Comment: @DenisGojinetchi what jkb means is that `"D://jobs.txt"` should be either `"D:\\jobs.txt"` or `"D:/jobs.txt"`

Comment: @DenisGojinetchi "*it tells me that file is not included in directory*" - no, it doesn't, because there is no such logic in the code shown.  You are not validating that `infile.open()` is successful or not before attempting to read data from `infile`.

Comment: @DenisGojinetchi on a side note: `while(infile>>element1 && infile >> element2 && infile>>element3)` can be simpilfied to `while(infile >> element1 >> element2 >> element3)`. But that is not going to work, because that does not account for the `,` between the integers.

Comment: How can I solve this problem with comas ?

Comment: Well, a test shows me that 'D://jobs.txt" is a valid path on Windows. Your problem seems to be that you're saying in your program that your file is in the root directory of drive D, but you say your file is in your program directory and your desktop. These are not the same things. Try opening the file without the "D://" part.

Comment: @DenisGojinetchi "*How can I solve this problem with comas ?*" - by actually reading the commas, in addition to reading the integers. See the answer I just posted

Comment: jkb, none of them works, for other project that I used same exactly code is working but for this one doesn't

Comment: Now that you've provided your error message, your problem seems to be that your program source file name has spaces, but is not quoted in the `g++` command. Try something like `g++ "first problem.cpp" -o "first problem"`. You're probably better off removing the space from your source file name.

Comment: yeah, this is what I did, replaced space and it worked, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You are not validating that the `ifstream` is successfully opening the file.

But more importantly, you are not handling the `,` characters that are in between the integers.  When `operator>>` is reading an integer, it will stop reading on the first non-digit character it encounters, *leaving that character in the stream*.  The next call to `operator>>` will try to read an integer, encounter that `,` immediately, and fail, leaving the stream in an error state that you are not `clear()`'ing,, and thus breaking your loop prematurely.

You need to read and discard the `,` characters.  Try something more like this:

```cpp
int main(){
    
    ifstream infile("D:\\jobs.txt");
    if (!infile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Can't open file" << endl;
    }
    else {
        vector<int> vec1, vec2, vec3;
        int element1, element2, element3;
        char comma;

        while (infile >> element1 >> comma >> element2 >> comma >> element3)
        {
            vec1.push_back(element1);
            vec2.push_back(element2);
            vec3.push_back(element3);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/EciHII)

Comment: still same problem for me, 
C:\Users\Denis\OneDrive\Desktop\Seattle U\3500\first assignment> cd "c:\Users\Denis\OneDrive\Desktop\Seattle U\3500\first assignment\" ; if ($?) { g++ first problem.cpp -o first problem } ; if ($?) { .\first problem }
g++.exe: error: first: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: problem.cpp: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: problem: No such file or directory
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
PS C:\Users\Denis\OneDrive\Desktop\Seattle U\3500\first assignment>

Comment: That is not a runtime error when running the code shown. That is a compiler error. Your `.cpp` filename contains a space character in it. Note the error message is complaining about `first`, not `first problem`. You need to wrap such filenames in quotes, eg: `g++ "first problem.cpp" -o "first problem"` ... `".\first problem"` A better option is to simply not put spaces in source code file names to begin with.

Comment: omg, stupid me. thanks for help, didn't know this is a problem